# Sound wave direction of polarization in liquid and solid

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

In Statistical Physics, part 2 by Landau and Lifschitz, second 22, it's written that the sound wave only has longitudinal direction of polarization in liquid while both longitudinal and tranverse in solid.
My question is why there is such a difference in liquid and solid. Which feature cause this difference?

Answer (score 1):

In order for wave phenomena to occur, a restoring force is needed (at least in the classical picture). In solid, transverse displacement will result in a restoring force that make an atom oscillate about its lattice site; whereas in liquid phase (at least for Newtonian liquid, see footnote for the non-Newtonian case), there is no such restoring force from transverse displacement.

Footnote: For [non-Newtonian fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid), as it has a shear-dependent viscosity, I think it is in principle possible for transverse oscillation to occur. However, I am not completely sure, so anyone with more knowledge on this should comment.